# What kind of text formatting is possible in reply of the question in Ask Ubuntu?

Tags: support, comments, formatting

I'm a newbie on Ask Ubuntu.

I can use the text formatting in the body of question in Ask Ubuntu.
Then, what kind of text formatting is possible in reply of the question?
I did not find such information in the help center.

Comment: Hello, this question should be asked on meta. Anyway, this https://askubuntu.com/editing-help should help you

Comment: "Then, what kind of text formmating is possible in reply of the question?" Do you mean in answers or comments? Answers have all the same options as questions but comments have limitations https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work

Comment: I mean the text formatting in comment.